# Question About Batch Variables and the Call Method

Tags: windows, batch-file, variables, call

I am trying to figure out how to use call appropriately to pass variables backwards (to the original batch file that calls other batch files).

The way I have my batch files currently setup is my main batch file calls other batch files which may then even call a third batch file which creates the variable.

Here are some examples of my scripts so far, for this example I will be focusing on main.bat, VerifyCredentials.bat, and the CreateAdminCreds.bat files. In these I am trying to pass the %AdminUser% and %AdminPass% variables back to main.bat:

**main.bat example:**

```
REM Define all the variables that will be updated by other batch files.
set NewCompName= & set DomainUser= & set DomainPass= & set AdminUser= & set AdminPass=

REM Create the variables for the domain tech account and local admin account. Verify tech account can access SCCM file share.
set CredTestVar=0
:CredTestLoop
call CreateCompName.bat & call VerifyCredentials.bat & call TestCredentials.bat
if %CredTestVar% LSS 1 goto CredTestLoop

REM Activate the local admin account and set password
ECHO Enabling Administrator account
net user administrator /active:yes
net user administrator "%AdminPass%"
ECHO.
```

**VerifyCredentials.bat example:**

```
@ECHO off

if not exist Credentials\DomainUser.txt call CreateDomainCreds.bat
if not exist Credentials\DomainPass.txt call CreateDomainCreds.bat

for /f "delims=" %%x in (Credentials\DomainUser.txt) do set DomainUser=%%x
for /f "delims=" %%x in (Credentials\DomainPass.txt) do set DomainPass=%%x

if not exist Credentials\AdminUser.txt call CreateAdminCreds.bat
if not exist Credentials\AdminPass.txt call CreateAdminCreds.bat

for /f "delims=" %%x in (Credentials\AdminUser.txt) do set AdminUser=%%x
for /f "delims=" %%x in (Credentials\AdminPass.txt) do set AdminPass=%%x
```

**CreateAdminCreds.bat example:**

```
@ECHO off

REM Create and define the local administrator credentials
:CreateAdmin
cls
echo.
echo Please enter a new password for the local Administrator account
echo.
set "AdminUser=Administrator"
set /p "AdminPass=Administrator Password:"
goto :ResponseAdmin

:ResponseAdmin
set "AdminAnswer="
cls
echo.
echo The Administrator password is "%AdminPass%"
echo.
set /p "AdminAnswer=Is this correct? (y/n):"
if %AdminAnswer%==y () else (if %AdminAnswer%==n (goto :CreateAdmin) else (goto :ResponseAdmin))

(echo=%AdminUser%) > "Credentials\AdminUser.txt"
(echo=%AdminPass%) > "Credentials\AdminPass.txt"
set "AdminAnswer="
```

So all of this individually works fine.. but when I get to the step in main.bat where I try to use that variable %AdminPass% for the tech to define the local admin account it doesn't change the password to anything (on restart/lock you can login to local admin without a password)

Can anyone help explain to me why the variable %AdminPass% is not being passed back to main.bat?
I have tested this passing theory like this:

**test1.bat**

```
@ECHO off

set testvar=
echo testvar is currently equal to %testvar%
REM this returns "testvar is currently equal to"
call test2.bat
echo testvar is now equal to %testvar%
REM this returns "testvar is now equal to something"
```

**test2.bat**

```
@ECHO off

set testvar="something"
```

and this successfully changes testvar to something for the second echo in the test1.bat file.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: You have not stated whether you are doing this on a domain, and if you are running these elevated. I would assume that normal users would not be allowed to create/change the password for the special administrator account, and would therefore need to elevate in order to do so. BTW, line 1 of your main.bat is incorrect, as the line below it, which should be ```Set "NewCompName=" & Set "DomainUser=" & Set "DomainPass=" & Set "AdminUser=" & Set "AdminPass="``` doesn't define anything, it undefines five variables, if they exist.

Comment: BTW your `VerifyCredentials.bat` could be reduced to just these three lines **1.** ```@For %%G In (User Pass) Do For %%H In (Domain Admin) Do @(```, **2.** ```If Not Exist "Credentials\%%H%%G.txt" Call "Create%%HCreds.bat"```, **3.** ```Set /P "%%H%%G=" 0<"Credentials\%%H%%G.txt")```. Please note however that none of your scripts are specifically defining the current working directory. That means that the ```Credentials``` directory is really acting as ```.\Credentials``` which means it is relative to the current directory. For that reason `main.bat` should define that working directory first.

Comment: @Compo Thank you for the suggestion for VerifyCredentials.bat I am quite new to batch and didn't know I could do that. That is quite powerful and handy.

As for the first comment, I wasn't sure if I had to define empty variables first or not for the main.bat to be able to use the newly assigned values in the called files. Also these are ran as a buildout script so this is ran as a local admin account prior to domain join. I also state the path in another file which calls main after robocopying the entire buildout script from a USB to the C:\LexiconAutoDeploy directory.

Comment: There is no such thing as an empty variable; if there is no value, then it is not defined at all. I would suggest you leave the `REM`ark, just change the string `Define` to `Undefine`. Then change the line below it to match that which I've already given, _(in my first comment)_. I would still ask that you verify that a local account whiich is a member of the Administrators group is allowed to create/change the password for the Administrator account.

Answer (score 0):

When a `cmd` instance starts, it is provided with a set of string variables which form the `environment` (always strings - if the value of any string is all-numeric, then it can often be used in calculations.)

Any batch file that runs within that instance can modify, add to, or delete variables. Hence running batch files `A` and `B` in that order would allow `B` to see values established by `A`, but in the reverse order, those values would not be set.

It's therefore usual practice to follow the initial `@echo off` command (which turns command-regurgitation to the console for debugging OFF) by a `setlocal` command, which itself has various options. Fundamentally, a `setlocal` establishes a local environment with a copy of the environment as it stood when the `setlocal` was executed.

`setlocal`s may be nested, and are closed by an `endlocal` command or by reaching the physical end-of-file, whereupon the environment is restored to its condition at the time the matching `setlocal` was executed. Note that this applies only to the environment, it does not affect the setting of the durrent directory or drive for instance.

So, if `A` calls `B` then `B` will **NOT** manipulate `A`'s environment if `B` uses `setlocal`. If `B` has no `setlocal` then it will manipulate `A`'s environment **BUT** if run from the prompt, it will manipulate the `cmd instance`'s environment, which is generally undesirable.

There is a method to transmit the variable "over the endlocal barrier" like this:

```
endlocal&set "fred=%fred%"
```

which seems quite bizarre. What this does is use `cmd`'s parser. The entire line is parsed, and `%fred%` is replaced by the current value of the variable `fred` within the inner environment, and *then* the line `endlocal&set "fred=fredsvalue"` is executed; two commands, serially. So the inner environment is discarded and then the variable in the calling environment is set to the value.

So - you pays your money, you takes your choice. Use `setlocal` in the `call`ed routines, and you'll need to jump the `endlocal` barriers. Omit the `setlocal` and the `call`ed routine will manipulate the current environment.